# How to set math equation boldface in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

How can I set the font of the `tcolorbox` content as boldfaced

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!5!gray]
$x=\sqrt{y}$
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Also still intrigued how the colors are defined in `colback=white!5!gray`

Comment: the `!` colour syntax is defined and documented in the `xcolor` package see `texdoc xcolor`

Comment: to get bold math anywhere (not just in `tcolorbox`) use `\boldmath $...$`

Answer (score 3):

There are two questions: colour specification with `!` and the bold face type.

1. Colour specification: `\color{green!40!yellow}` means a `40%` mixture of the colour `green` and `60%` of `yellow`. In this case `white!5!gray` means a very dark gray background, since `white` does not contribute much to the colour here.
2. Bold face can be either used with `fontupper=\bfseries` for text mode or `code=\boldmath`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

No boldmath: $x=\sqrt{y}$

Grouped boldmath: {\boldmath $x=\sqrt{y}$}



\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!5!gray]
  $ x=\sqrt{y}$

  \boldmath{$ x=\sqrt{y}$}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title={All boldmath},code={\boldmath},colback=white!5!gray]
  $ x=\sqrt{y}$
\end{tcolorbox}

No boldmath again: $E=mc^{2}$


\end{document}
```

[image]